# Laravel, no puedo comprobar el Auth::user() en llamadas ajax. Y por tanto cualquiera puede ejecutar dicha llamada

Tags: laravel, ajax

os pongo en situacion. En mi app hay usuarios **normales y admins**. Pues para los admins hay una tabla donde **activar/desactivar** usuarios. El boton llama a un ajax que si esta activado lo desactiva y viceversa.

Ahora bien, al ser un ajax, y tener dicha ruta en `api.php`, no puedo comprobar el usuario logeado y ver que **si no es admin no pueda activar/desactivar**.

**api.php**

```
Route::get('/user/toggle-activate', 'UserController@toggleActivateUser')->name('api.user.toggle-activate');
```

**UserController@toggleActivateUser**

```
    public function toggleActivateUser(Request $request){
if (!$request->user()->isAdmin()){abort(401);}//linea conflictiva !!

        $userId = $request->user_id;

        $user = User::findOrFail($userId);

        if ($user->active == 1){
            $user->active = 0;
        }
        else{
            $user->active = 1;
        }


            $updatedUser = $user->save();
        if ($updatedUser){
            $message = "El usuario $user->name";
            $user->active == 1? $message .= " se ha activado correctamente":$message.=" se ha desactivado correctamente";
        }
        else {
            $message = "Ha ocurrido un error al";
            $user->active != 1? $message .= " desactivar ":$message=" activar";
            $message .= " el usuario $user->name";
        }

        return response()->json(['updated'=>$updatedUser,'message'=>$message]);

    }
```

Aqui esta el problema :

```
if (!$request->user()->isAdmin()){abort(401);}
```

No puedo acceder al user de esa manera, ni con `auth()->user()` entonces puede entrar cualquiera...

**La llamada ajax de la vista**

/**
* Ajax activate-toggler
*/

```
function activateToggler(userId,button){
    var url =  '{{route('api.user.toggle-activate')}}';
    button = $(button);
    console.log('uer id ='+userId);
    console.log('url ='+url);
    // console.log('button ',button.toggleClass('btn-danger','btn-success'))
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'GET',
        url         :  url,
        data: {'user_id':userId},
        dataType    : 'json',
        success: function(data){
            if (data.updated){
                alert(data.message);
                button.removeClass();
                button.addClass('btn btn-sm');
                if (button.text() === 'Activar'){
                    button.text('Desactivar');
                    button.addClass('btn-danger');
                }
                else{
                    button.text('Activar');
                    button.addClass('btn-success');

                }

            }
        },
        error:  function (error){
            alert('Ha ocurrido un error al activar/desactivar el usuario');
            console.log('error')
            console.log(error)
        }
    });
}
```

El mensaje de error es :

```
"message": "Call to a member function isAdmin() on null"
```

Pues que `$request->user()` no devuelve una instancia de User

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Has intentado implementar dentro de tus rutas un grupo middleware? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-middleware

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {

    });

    Route::get('/user/profile', function () {

    });
});
```

Incluso no tiene que ser dentro de un grupo, puedes atribuírle el método de middleware en la misma ruta, por ejemplo:

`routes/web.php`

`Route::get('/', [AdminController::class, 'index'])->middleware();`

Puedes verificar roles también en tus rutas, por ejemplo:

```
Route::filter('admin', function()
{ 
  if ( Auth::user()->admin !==1) {
     return Redirect::to('/'); 
   }
});
```